# Personal enabled systemd service doesn't start on boot

Tags: linux

So I have a script in `/etc/scripts` that just has one line which adds a static arp entry using the `arp -s` command. In `/etc/systemd/system` I created a service file which contains the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Add static arp entry for gateway

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/scripts/add_arp_entry.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi.user.target
```

When I run `systemctl is-enabled add_arp_entry.service` I get "enabled" as output.
When I run `systemctl status add_arp_entry.service` I see that the service is enabled but is inactive.
I can start it but the services ends by itself after execution of the script. I think it is okay in this case because I don't know why this script would need to be active all the time. I think maybe the service doesn't run because it's not active before the reboot?

Comment: It's normal for services to be marked "inactive (dead)" after they have exited successfully.

Comment: Yeah that actually makes sense. I don't get why the service doesn't get started again after the system just rebooted though. As I tried editing my script that it would make a random file in /etc I saw that it doesn't get executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's `multi-user.target` not `multi.user.target`. The latter target does not exist, so your service is never started.

Comment: Even after applying the following change, I still see the script doesn't get executed.
It's weird because when I manually started my service in the past with the wrong target it did what it was supposed to do.